# C# WCF Service Get Status Code in Client from One way Service

Tags: c#, wcf, httpresponse, http-response-codes

I have a WCF service which has a method named ArchiveFile(string fileName) which basically archives files. I have created a proxy project using svcutil and added its reference created in my client application and is consuming the service as follows:

```
        var binding = new WSHttpBinding { Security = new WSHttpSecurity() { Mode = SecurityMode.None } };
        var address = new EndpointAddress(this.TargetUrl);
        var fileService = new FileServiceClient(binding, address);'
```

I want to know how do I determine the Http Status Code (200 - OK or any other) for the WCF Service call.

Answer (score 0):

We can get the http status code through WebOperationContext Class:

```
 WebOperationContext statuscode = WebOperationContext.Current;
 Console.WriteLine(statuscode.OutgoingResponse.StatusCode);
```

For more information about WebOperationContext,please refer to the following link:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.web.weboperationcontext?view=netframework-4.8